# Отображение данных в браузере Safari

Tags: angularjs, safari

[image: отображение проблемы]

Проблема состоит в том, что при замене теста с помощью angularjs в браузере Safari происходят такие проблемы с отображением. Либо же замена данных происходит, но Safari почему то их не перерисовует при произойденом событии. Во всех других браузерах все отлично работает. Как бороться с этой проблемой?